# My OpenWRT router keeps running out of space on the root filesystem

Tags: router, openwrt

I flashed my router (TP-Link WDR4300) with OpenWRT Barrier Breaker several months ago. It has been working fine until a couple of days ago when tried to add some URLs to the DNS forwarding section. The file refused to save with the error "No space left on device". I then ran `df` and it showed:

```
rootfs-> [ 1K-blocks  4736 ][ Used  4628 ][ Available  108 ][ Use%  98% ]
```

To free up some space, I deleted a package I had installed but didn't use. Everything was fine, but today again same error. I can only imagine some log or something keeps growing and taking up space. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out because I had a cron job for wget to a URL which i need updated for my DNS service, everytime the wget command was ran (which was hourly) the html file would be saved and I didnt setup a command to delete it, this is what was consuming the memory.